# Angular directive using isolated scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to make an Angular directive which takes some data and modifies a scope variable based on the input, but I can't get it to work.

Here is a simplified version of my JS:

```
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.directive('checkDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { line: '@' },
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.newLine = $scope.line;
    },
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">                           
    0
    <check-directive line="...">
        a{{line}}b{{newLine}}c
    </check-directive>
    1
</div>
```

A fiddle for it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/60/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think your isolated scope in your directive is not accessible to the controller. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735433/1454888. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Transcluded HTML scope is a child of the parent's scope, not the directive scope.  You can use the `transclude` function that is passed to the directive's linking function to change the scope.

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
  transcludeFn(scope, function (clone, scope) {
    elem.append(clone);
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/64/

I wouldn't recommend doing this, though.  Instead it makes more sense to me to assume that the transcluded content is going to be using a separate scope and work with that.  You can create a separate directive too if need be.

Comment: Not technically correct.  Transclusion, by default, creates a new scope that is a child of the parent scope (that prototypically inherits from the parent).  This scope is a sibling of the directive scope.  It is a minor detail, but can have interesting and undesirable side effects if you assume otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

That's because the transcluded HTML doesn't use the isolated scope of the directive, but the one of its parent. The way to use the right scope is using the specific `transclude` parameter of the link function.

Also, `@` means angular expect an expression between curly brackets, such as `{{someVariable}}` or `{{ 'someString' }}`

http://jsfiddle.net/floribon/r611o3sa/

```
module.directive('checkDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { line: '@' },
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {   
      var isolatedScope = scope;

      transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
        scope.line = isolatedScope.line;
        scope.newLine = scope.line;
      });
    },
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

You should read more about transclusion here: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/