# Angular - scope variable update in controller function call doesn't get reflected in directive html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been playing around with angular trying to understand how it manages scopes, then I found that I couldn't update the variables in the directive using a function call.

To illustrate the issue, here is my simple app:
The idea is that when you click the toggle link, the menu should show up and when you click it again or somewhere else, the menu should disappear.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('DemoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  }])
  .directive('dropdown', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.onBlur = function () {
          // this doesn't actually work
          $scope.showMenu = false;
        };
      },
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body id="body" ng-app="app" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <dropdown ng-transclude>
    <a href="#" ng-click="showMenu = !showMenu" ng-blur="onBlur()">Toggle</a>
    <menu ng-show="showMenu">
      <div>I'm</div>
      <div>the drop-down</div>
      <div>menu</div>
    </menu>
  </dropdown>
</body>
```

Here's my plunker links:

Non-working version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rfdt5FEoGAOX15RZUsKA?p=preview

Working version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xMANGDVa8n64OKK3gOgg?p=preview

The difference between the working one and the other is that the working version simply uses `ng-blur="showMenu = false"` instead of calling the function. If I call `$scope.$apply()` inside the controller function, then I will get "$apply already in progress" exception.

I guess I must be missing something here but I've no idea why right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `$scope.$apply()`. Use `$timeout( function(){ .... })`. It will avoid the "already in progress" error.

Comment: @JeremyThille Neither are required here.

Comment: Still, the trick stands =)

Comment: True! Worth noting, but also worth noting that neither should be used if at all possible. @NSF Your usage of `$scope.showMenu = false` is fine, what you're doing in your controller is right - however I can't help but think this is due to the way Angular is handling the focus/blur events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs one thing about $scope.$apply() function it is possible to call it only when $scope.$$phase is empty (make sure its not in $digest or $apply phase)

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) {
   $scope.$apply()
}
```

In your first plunker change only this:

```
$scope.showMenu = false;
to 
this.showMenu = false;
```

its in function and function is already $scope bind.

Comment: wow that totally does the work! By using console.log, it seems that inside the function call, "this" refers to the original scope and $scope is a new scope. I wonder if there's documentation mentioning why the behavior is like that.

Comment: This is problem with javascript, not actually angularjs. You have defined function under the $scope, and inside this function "this" is same as that original $scope, but if you use $scope in function javascript binds this variable with totally different $scope.

Comment: This is what i got - console.log(this): ChildScope {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array[1], $$listeners: Object…}, console.log($scope): Object {$$childTail: ChildScope, $$childHead: ChildScope, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $$listeners: Object…} May I ask where the second scope comes from?

Comment: @NSF The second scope is created when you use `ng-transclude`. I know it's long-winded, but this answer is superb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653004/confused-about-angularjs-transcluded-and-isolate-scopes-bindings

Comment: @AlexG Actually I later figured out that wasn't an issue with javascript but still angular. When transclude is used, angular creates a sibling scope not under but next to the directive scope. When the function gets called, angular binds the scope in the transcluded template to the "this" reference in that function. The $scope var is still the directive scope intact, and because it's a sibling scope, the change doesn't get prototypically inherited to the other one.