# Nested - transcluded items - scope clarification?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

*I already know how transclusion works ( within first level  only I guess) , bUt I have a question about nested transcluded item's scope.*

Ok so I have this code :

```
<body ng-app="docsTabsExample" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <my-tabs>
    <my-pane title="Hello">
      <h4>Hello , The value of "i" is => {{i}}</h4>
   </my-pane>
  </my-tabs>
</body>
```

Basically I have a `controller` , `<my-tabs>` and `<my-pane >`.

Looking at `myTabs` directive :

```
  .directive('myTabs', function()
  {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          transclude: true,
          scope:
          {},
          controller: ['$scope', function($scope)
          {
              $scope.i = 2;
          }],
          template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
      };
  })
```

I know that the content of the directive *will have access to the **outer** directive's scope*

So the yellow part will have access to the outer scope ( which is the main controller scope) :

[image]

Here is the code for `myPane` directive :

```
  .directive('myPane', function()
  {
      return {
          require: '^myTabs',
          restrict: 'E',
          transclude: true,
          scope:
          {
          },
          controller: function($scope)
          {
              $scope.i = 4; //different value
          },
          template: '<div  ng-transclude></div>'
      };
  })
```

The program starts with  :

```
.controller('ctrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.i = 1000;
})
```

The output of the program is :

> Hello , The value of "i" is => 1000

**But**

According to the documentation  : `myPane's` transcluded data should have access to the outer scope of the directive which is `myTabs` directive which has the value `i=2`.

But `myPane` has an *isolated* scope so it does *NOT* inherit the scope from `myTabs`.

**Question**

So   does  it goes one level **more** higher to the controller's scope in order to get `i=1000` ?? <sub>(Clarification , I'm not asking how can I make `i` get another value - I'm asking why/how it has the value of 1000).</sub>

I mean how does the hierarchy of scope looks here?

Is it like this?

```
         controller's scope
                |
       +--------+---------+
       |                  |
  myTabs's             mypanes's
 transcluded           transcluded 
 data's scope          data's scope
```

the docs says :

> The transclude option changes the way scopes are nested. It makes it
>   so that the contents of a transcluded directive have **whatever scope is
>   outside the directive**, rather than whatever scope is on the inside. In
>   doing so, it gives the contents access to the outside scope.

But what scope does the outside of `myPAne` directive has ?

In other words , why/*how* does `i=1000`?

[**FULL PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cpHnl4I3abAx5R4oJVKH?p=preview)

**EDIT FROM OP AFTER ANSWER**

After installing and configuring PeriScope ( from @MarkRajcok) I can now see it visually :

[image]

Comment: Both myTab and myPane have `transclude: true`. myPane is nested within myTab. You're giving myPane the scope of myTab, and then myTab the scope of ctrl, which gives myPane the scope of ctrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on [$compile](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion)

> When you call a transclude function it returns a DOM fragment that is
>   pre-bound to a transclusion scope. This scope is special, in that it
>   is a child of the directive's scope (and so gets destroyed when the
>   directive's scope gets destroyed) but it inherits the properties of
>   the scope from which it was taken.

**Parent** Hierarchy (from $$childTail) is like:

```
-1 (root)
--2 (ctrl)
---3 mytab
----4 ($$transcluded = true)
------5 mypane
--------6 ($$transcluded = true)
```

**Prototypical Hierarchy** is like (screenshot from AngularJS Batarang)-

[image: ng-transclude proto hierarchy]

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ku8h2MHPRSGAv4NEs7W7?p=preview) with scope id's printed in console should give you a better idea.

Why these are different, I am not very sure. Someone can throw light on this.

Why the value is 1000. Its because **i** needs to be provided as a **bidirectional** attribute **=** so the child scopes can modify it. I have updated the above plunker, you can see now the value responds to change in `pane` controller.

More on transcluded scopes - 
[Confused about Angularjs transcluded and isolate scopes & bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653004/confused-about-angularjs-transcluded-and-isolate-scopes-bindings) 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Why did you add i to the isolated scope? My question did not has it. Also - in your plunker - can you please explain what is "mypane parent 4" ? I know that both mytabs and mypane has isolated(different) scope. but what is `mypane parent 4`? What is the parent of mypane ?

Comment: Transcluded scope is a special scope. In the case above - `mypane parent 4` is the transcluded scope. I have updated the post with a link that explains transcluded scope.

Comment: But my question has 2 transcluded items  , so why do I see only the 4'th one ?

Comment: Right. There is actually a 6th scope as well. I have updated the post. 2 for directives, 2 transcluded, rootscope and ctrl.