# Angular changing parent model from transclude scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm confused from angular transclude scope. I'm trying to make let say collapsible directive. But binding inside the transclude scope will not change model of parent unless I use some object for the model eg. data.

```
<div>
  data.prop: {{data.prop}} <br>
  prop: {{prop}}
  <collapsible>
    data.prop: <input type="text" ng-model="data.prop" /> <br> // WILL CHANGE PARENT
    prop: <input type="text" ng-model="prop" /> // WONT CHANGE PARENT
  </collapsible>
</div>
```

I already read this topic and still I don't get it why I must use prefix to the model.
[Confused about Angularjs transcluded and isolate scopes & bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653004/confused-about-angularjs-transcluded-and-isolate-scopes-bindings)

Working example at http://plnkr.co/edit/z3IvR1a37jdNRCJWG0Yq?p=preview

In my app I'm using object for forms, so it works fine but I just want to know why is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an object to bind to the model, your object is passed to the different scope as an reference, not a copy, in `Javascript` objects are passed to functions as a reference. In that case it will still reference to previous scope.

Comment: Thank you, It seems reasonable.